# How to make a JQuery slider

Tags: jquery, slider

Here's what I have in mind: Have four images and when clicked on one a panel shows up with some information I want. When I click on another image the old panel disappears and a new one opens in the same spot. I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#img1").click(function(){
    $("#panel").show("slow");
  });
});

<div id="panel1">
<img src="images/image1">
Some text
</div>

<img id="img1" src="some image">
<img id="img2" src="some image">

...
```

But this way when I click on a second image the old panel doesn't disappear and the new one opens under the first.

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: It depents on what you like to display and how. Recent i've created a slider that loaded dynamic content. But i didn't like to have every single item pre loaded into html so i used a slider + jQuery ajax to load the content into a `div`. Maybe show your html and what you like to display and how you like it to display, (for example http://lenders-it.nl/v2/)

Comment: @mattytommo I've added the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img1").click(function(){
    $(".image:visible").hide();
    $("#panel").show("slow");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How can you expect the old panel to close when you don't command it to do so?

Here's what I'd do (not tested):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('img').click(function () {
    var img = $(this);
    var panel = $('#panel');
    panel.hide();
    panel.html(img.data('info'));
    panel.show('slow');
  })
});
```

### the html part:

```
<img src="img1.jpg" data-info="information for the image" />
<img src="img2.jpg" data-info="information for the image" />
<img src="img3.jpg" data-info="information for the image" />
<div id="panel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Give a css class `.panel` to every `panel`:

```
<div id="panel1" class='panel'>
<div id="panel2" class='panel'>
...........
```

then `hide the panelid` and `show the corresponding panel`:

```
$("#img1").click(function(){
   $('.panel').slideUp();
   $("#panel1").show('slow');
});

$("#img2").click(function(){
   $('.panel').slideUp();
   $("#panel2").show('slow');
});
```